For subscriptions that are billed like weekly, monthly, annually, etc. do they bill at the start and give you the time or give you the time then bill?
I was searching google but I only got unrelated websites.

Depends on the contract. Either way is possible.

If that's true, then I was wondering: what happens you don't pay in the latter circumstance?

Again, depends on the contract.

Typically, it is on the anniversary of your sign up in my experience.

@Jerry Probably they send your debt to collection or sue you via small claims court or whatever equivalent in your jurisdiction exists.

My UK Labour Party membership does one, and my Virgin Media/O2 broadband does the opposite. My mobiole phone bills halfway through the month, so it's 50% each.

@PeteB. The question is whether they're billing in arrears or not, not when they bill.


For subscriptions that are billed like weekly, monthly, annually, etc.
do they bill at the start and give you the time or give you the time
then bill?

How they bill depends on how they want to operate. They can bill in small or large chunks. When you pay could be before you get the first month of service, or it could be after the first month.
I would think that this has changed over the decades. You are no longer sending in a postcard card to a company, or calling a toll-free number to get a subscription started.  You are no longer mailing in a check to pay for the subscription.
When you signup on the website this is the perfect time to gather your billing information.
You haven't even mentioned the model where the first period is either free or heavily discounted. They know that some people will never stay beyond the free or discounted period.
There is another model where they start you for free and hope that you forget that they collected the billing information, and they hope that you don't turn it off before the expensive months start.
It can be even worse when the paid version is snuck into the process. You see this when you signup to do a 5K, and they collect the entree fee, but then sneak-in an agreement for some monthly service that you don't need or want.
